# Move exceeding list items to next column in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having a row with two columns as shown in the snippet below.
Here in **Column 1** there are **7** list items under `ul` tag.

But i am in the need to show **Only 5** list items in column 1 and the rest of the items should move to the next column.. (i.e to **Column 2**).

How can i achieve the result to move the list items automatically to next column based on the count (here its 5), if the list items exceeding above count (5)..

And the result expected to be only in html and css and there should not be any library like jquery or any other third party.

**Current Snippet:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4 mr-4">
 <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">List Item 4</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">List Item 5</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">List Item 6</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">List Item 7</li>
</ul>
 </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 mr-4">
 Column-2
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4 mr-4">
     <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">List Item 1</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">List Item 2</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">List Item 3</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">List Item 4</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">List Item 5</li>
    </ul>
     </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 mr-4">
     <ul class="list-group">
       <li class="list-group-item">List Item 6</li>
       <li class="list-group-item">List Item 7</li>
    </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to move elements from one DOM container to another with CSS.

One can change the layout *behaviour* in a single container though and CSS-Grid can do that **without requiring a fixed height**.....using the explicit and implict grid.

```css
ul.list-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap:1em;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 mr-4">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 1</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 3</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 4</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 5</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 6</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 7</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 8</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 9</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">List Item 10</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can i align the items at centre if there is only one column say only 4 items is there so only one row will be there and it should be aligned centre.. I have used ```justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;``` but its not making centre alignment.

Comment: You'd need to put the `.col-xs-4 ` column in the center of the **row**. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RYoMdM

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using flexbox, but both the flex container (`.list-group` in this case) and flex items (`.list-group-item`) need to have explicit height in order to wrap properly.

And a little side-note: don't use `col-xs` with Bootstrap 4, use `col` instead.

```css
.list-group {
  height: 200px;
}

.list-group-item {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mr-4">
    <ul class="list-group d-flex flex-column flex-wrap">
      <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wanted 5 items in one column